# invocation of remote command does not work with p:fileDownload

Tags: primefaces

I would like to invoke a command at the start of the download of a file (the remotecommand updateEditUd1) but it does not work

```
<p:column>                       
 <p:commandButton value="Checkout" ajax="false" onclick="updateEditUd1()">
   <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadController.downloadXMLFile(editUDBean.mostRecentFile)}" />  
 /p:commandButton>
```

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateEditUd1" action="#{editUDBean.lockFile()}"/>
```

On another note, when I put ajax=true, the command is properly invoked, but the file is not downloaded.

Is there a workaround ?

EDIT

I tried to use onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(updateEditUd1, null)"

```
 <p:commandButton onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(updateEditUd1, null)
 <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadController.downloadXMLFile(editUDBean.mostRecentFile)}" />  
/p:commandButton>
```

But that did not work

Comment: Have you tried using PrimeFaces.monitorDownload ? in the start you may call the remoteCommand

Comment: Thanks Hatem Alimam !  i used onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)"> but it does not close the window.  Hiwever, I need only an action at the begin of the download. So I change to onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(updateEditUd1, null) but it does nothing. I suspect I did not correctly invoke my remote action